# How to establish constraint between variables with multiple indexes using CPLEX in Python

Tags: integer-programming, cplex, python, binary-variable, docplex

I am new in CPLEX and I am using docplex in Python to solve an ILP.

I would like to translate the following constraint in docplex:

$$\sum_{c}(X_p{_w}_{cj}+X_{p+1}{_{w'}}_{cj+1})\leqslant T_w{_{w'}}_{,jj+1} + 1$$

Knowing that the binary variables are:

- $X_p{_w}_{cj}=1$ if an operation $p$ is done by a machine $w$ with a configuration $c$ at process plan position $j$, and zero otherwise
- $T_w{_{w'}}_{,jj+1}=1$ if there is a change of machine $w$ between position $j$ and $j+1$, and zero otherwise.

I've tried to code a dictionary:

```py
cnrt_10 = {(w, w1, j-1, j): opt_model.add_constraint(ct=opt_model.sum(X_var[p-1, w, c, j-1] + X_var[p, w1, c, j] for c in set_C) <= 1 + T_var[w, w1, j-1, j], ctname="cnrt10_{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}".format(w, w1, j-1, j)) for p in set_OP for w in set_W for w1 in set_W for j in set_J}
```

And also a list:

```py
opt_model.add_constraints(opt_model.sum(X_var[p-1, w, c, j-1] + X_var[p, w1, c, j] for c in set_C) <= 1 + T_var[w, w1, j-1, j] for p in set_OP for w in set_W for w1 in set_W for j in set_J)
```

But both are returning an error.

I am sorry for my elementary question, but I am a beginner in Python and CPLEX, so I would really appreciate if someone can help me with these problems.

Comment: What is the error you're getting here? Also, I see that you're doing `for j in set_J` and you are accessing index `j-1` in your constraint (which I guess can lead to `IndexError` or `KeyError`)

Comment: How did you define your set indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a clarification in the comment, you have `KeyError` and more or less, this is what's happening:

You're looking at an index or key (in your dictionary) that doesn't exist and those are keys related to indices `j-1` and `p-1`. What you need to do is not to loop over all `set_J` and `set_OP`. So, for example, assuming `set_J = {1,2,3}`, you can't have an index of `j=0` which happens for the first time when `p=1` and `j=1` in your loop and `X_var[p-1, w, c, j-1]= X_var[0, 1, 1, 0]`. One way to avoid that is to say something like `for j in range(2, len(set_J)+1)` (Note that the idea is the same even if your `set_J` or `set_OP` are defined using other Python objects). Do the same thing for `set_OP` too.

Comment: Hello @EhsanK. Thank you very much for your reply. I tried to change the range of J, as you suggested me and it worked well. I really appreciated your help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a problem in the indices that you used in the construction of constraints. For example, you defined $T_w{_{w'}}_{,jj+1}$ which should have had 4 indices in your constraint while you put 5 of them.

> T_var[w, c, c1, j-1, j]

I am not an expert in DOcplex but I am familiar with Pyomo in which you can first define a "**ConstraintList()**" and then through a for loop, you can add instances of that type of constraint in the constraint list. I tried to model that part of the code even though it isn't exact but may give you some hints.

```py
model.cons_list = ConstraintList()
for c in set_C:
   for p in set_OP:
      for w, w1 in set_W: 
         for j in set_J:
            model.cons_list.add(sum(X_var[p-1, w, c, j-1] + X_var[p, w1, c, j]) <= 1 + T_var[w, c, c1, j-1, j])
```

Also you can use

```py
Constraint.Skip
```

for those combinations that you don't want to have a constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Oguz. I edited my post to rectify my mistake by entering T_var[w, w1, j-1, j]. Even when I try this one, the code does not run correctly, it returns a " KeyError: (0, 1, 1, 0)". I think it is related to dictionary key, but I really do not know how to rectify that, since I must use j-1.

Comment: Hello @Oguz Toragay, have you ever tried to work with a similar constraint in Pyomo? I implemented this constraint in docplex but the model is not able to understand the relation between X and T.

Comment: @campioni, unfortunately not, but try it in Pyomo, if you stack again, ask another question with all the clarifications that are necessary to understand your situation. I will definitely answer that if I can or I am sure someone will help you.